# Intellij: Go to autowired bean definition

Tags: intellij-idea

I looking for quick way to find bean definition by their @Autowired dependency in java code. Suppose I have:

```
@Autowired 
private JdbcTemplate template;
```

I want IDEA tell me in which xml file is the definition of `template` bean. How to do that?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @Morfic 13th version, Ultimate eddition

Comment: The answers below posted seem outdated, and I can't find a Spring plugin anyway in IDEA plugin part. Can someone post another suggestion, please?

Comment: @cinqS While the icons may have changed in the meantime, the answers are not outdated, they still apply. However, make sure you are using IntelliJ Idea ULTIMATE, and not the Community version, because the latter does not have all the features, including spring support ([click here for edition comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html))

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you have the spring plugin installed and active you should see some icons on the left gutter which help you to identify the place where the bean has been defined, either xml or annotation. If you have multiple spring profiles you may have to chose the active one.

[image]

Comment: I haven't. How to install?

Comment: It should've been installed by default with Idea. File -> Settings -> plugins (under IDE Settings). If present in the list but not enabled, tick the checkbox for the plugins. Otherwise click on `install jetbrains plugin`. If the plugins are already installed and active, make sure you have the spring facet added to the project. File -> Project struture -> Facets -> + -> Spring

Comment: Is there any shortcut for that? I can't find it.

Comment: @zeronone According to the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/navigating-to-declaration-or-type-declaration-of-a-symbol.html) you can use `CTRL` + `B` to navigate to its declaration place

Comment: @Morfic Sadly `CTRL+B` does not help here. For the field it navigates to its usages and for the type of the field it navigates to the type declaration, which is often (abstract super types or XML spring profile) not the bean definition. I cannot find a shortcut for the icon's function.

Comment: @StevenYang can you please be more specific about what exactly is happening?

Comment: Is the same function usable in eclipse with the spring plugin?

Comment: @lynxSven I don't think so, different IDEs, different plugins

Answer (score 2):

First install spring plugin by `Ctrl+Alt+S`
under IDE Settings, select Plugins.
In the right-hand part of the dialog, on the Plugins page, type spring in the search box.
If the check box to the left of Spring Support is not selected, select it. If you are going to use particular Spring frameworks (Spring Security, Spring Integration, etc.), make sure that the check boxes next to their names are also selected.

Then the icons on the left(near the code line-number) helps to identify the bean definition

Comment: I already selected, but it still not show any icon. it seems broken after 2020.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using CDI and not Spring but using [Go to Implementation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#go_to_implementation) keyboard shortcut achieves that as long as you have only one implementation of your interface in your classpath, otherwise it would pop a small dropdown menu.