# Spring support in IDEA with Lombok: Is "Navigate to autowired dependencies" supported?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, dependency-injection, lombok

Lombok supports to generate constructors with `@Inject` annotations:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
```

So, instead of

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    private final BarService barService;

    @Inject
    public FooService(BarService barService) {
        this.barService = barService;
    }
}
```

you can write

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class FooService {
    private final BarService barService;
}
```

My problem with that feature is that it seems to break Spring IDE support in IntelliJ:

- In the non-Lombok version, the IDE shows my where the autowired arguments come from and allows me to navigate to their locations (here, the implementation of the `BarService`).
- In the Lombok version, I cannot get it to work. It  still shows the location of the spring bean declaration, but not to the location of the autowired dependencies.

If I was the only developer, I would just use the first version and be done with it. However, I see that more and more code in our codebase is migrated to the Lombok constructor style. So, I am curious:

**Is it possible to use the full Spring support in IDEA in combination with Lombok `onConstructor = @__(@Inject)` constructors?**

Comment: Note that as of Spring 4.3, the constructor annotation is no longer required in the case of a singleton constructor.

Comment: Which kind of support is broken? Or rather, which did you expect? What do you mean by ‘the IDE shows my where the autowired arguments come from’? That dons not seem to be a feature that I am aware of.

Comment: This is still an issue even without the requirement to use @Inject. You can see an example of the feature here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454687/intellij-go-to-autowired-bean-definition Philipp, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: There are two open tickets with Jetbrains for this feature: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175127
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215368

Comment: @Tommy Unfortunately, I am not aware of a solution. Since middle of 2017, I am no longer working with Java in my day job, so I am not up-to-date with the recent developments of the tools.

Comment: As already pointed out, [this is a requested feature](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175127). One can workaround by adding `@Autowired` at the field level to find the bean declaration and then revert back to the original. I know it's dirty but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The lombok annotation `@RequiredArgsConstructor` will do the constructor based dependency injection.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FooService {
    private final BarService barService;
}
```

After Java 17 `record` will also do this like -

```
@Service
public record FooService(BarService barService) {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` annotation instead. It will autowire all your `final` fields. `@Inject` annotation is not very useful.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FooService {

    private final BarService barService;
}
```